# Does file truncate operation supported in Storage Access Framework (Android Lollipop API 21)?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, truncate, storage-access-framework

I need to truncate file on removable SD card. I can't call **truncate(someSize)** directly on a file due to Storage Access Framework (SAF) restrictions and forced to use:

```
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(documentFile.getUri(), "rw");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
    fileChannel = fos.getChannel();
    fileChannel.truncate(someSize);
```

As a result I have an exception:

```
java.nio.channels.NonWritableChannelException
    at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.checkWritable(FileChannelImpl.java:86)
    at java.nio.FileChannelImpl.truncate(FileChannelImpl.java:460)
```

Why above channel is not writable if I opened file descriptor in **rw** mode? Is there another way to truncate file under SAF on Lollipop!?

Comment: "Why above channel is not writable if I opened file descriptor in rw mode?" -- are you sure that wherever you are calling this code [still has permission to use that document](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html)?

Comment: I have no exception at this place when do the same thing on API 23. Code is exactly the same. Therefore, I suppose I have the permission...